# Unclear syntastic errors with ghc-mod

Tags: haskell, vim

This problem only appears to happen when I am using cabal sandboxes. Everytime i type check I get this error `syntastic: error: checker haskell/ghc_mod returned abnormal status 1` This error is very unhelpful is there anyway to make syntastic errors more verbose?

Comment: This is likely to be a problem with the way you run `ghc-mod`, not with syntastic.  But SO is not the place to debug it anyway, so please open an issue at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues).